# add advertising to html5 jquery mobile app, is it posible?

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, ads

I just made an android app using jquery mobile. I was wondering if it's posible to add some advertising using some services as admob or mobclick or similar. On my first research I couldnt find a proper sdk for this, they just have java sdk. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Millennial Media has a JavaScript API in beta (http://docs.millennialmedia.com/javascript-sdk/), but I've had some challenges getting it to work via an SSL-enabled HTML5/jQuery app. (looks like there might be a cert issue on the MMedia side)

Another option you might want to investigate is Amazon's new program: https://developer.amazon.com/post/Tx2HGWRGOW5YG8/Amazon-is-Now-Accepting-span-class-matches-HTML5-span-Web-Apps-8212-Making-it-Ea.html

I haven't had a chance to kick the tires on that yet, but it looks like a pretty good option as well.

If you elect to try either of those, please reply back with the results.

```
<?php
/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Millennial Media PHP Ad Coding, v.7.4.20                     */
/* Copyright Millennial Media, Inc. 2006                        */
/*                                                              */
/* The following code requires PHP >= 4.3.0 and                 */
/* allow_url_fopen 1 set in php.ini file.                       */
/*                                                              */
/* NOTE:                                                        */
/* It is recommended that you lower the default_socket_timeout  */
/* value in the php.ini file to 5 seconds.                      */
/* This will prevent network connectivity from affecting        */
/* page loading.                                                */
/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*------- Publisher Specific Section -------*/

// GET ADDITIONAL VARIABLES
$mm_placementid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['apid']);
$userLat = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['userLat']);
$userLon = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['userLon']);
$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['gender']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['age']);

if (strtoupper($gender) == "M" || strtoupper($gender) == "MALE") {
    $gender = "male";
} else if (strtoupper($gender) == "F" || strtoupper($gender) == "FEMALE"){
    $gender = "female";
}

// GET USER ZIPCODE
if (isset($userLat) && isset($userLon)) {
    $url = "http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON?lat=" . $userLat . "&lng=" . $userLon . "&radius=0.1&username=YOURACCOUNTHERE";
    $cURL = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json'
    ));
    $result = curl_exec($cURL);
    curl_close($cURL);
    $json = json_decode($result, true);
    $postalCode = $json['postalCodes'][0]['postalCode'];
} else {
    $postalCode = "";
}

$mm_adserver = "ads.mp.mydas.mobi";

/* The default response will be echo'd on the page     */
/* if no Ad is returned, so any valid WML/XHTML string */
/* is acceptable.                                      */
$mm_default_response = "";

/*------------------------------------------*/

/*----------- BEGIN AD INITIALIZATION ----------*/
/*----- PLEASE DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE -----*/
$mm_id = "NONE";
$mm_ua = "NONE";
@$mm_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] )){
    $mm_ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
} 

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_UP_SUBNO'])) {
          $mm_id = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_UP_SUBNO'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_XID'])) {
          $mm_id = $_SERVER['HTTP_XID'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENTID'])) {
          $mm_id = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENTID'];
} else {
          $mm_id = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$mm_url = "http://$mm_adserver/getAd.php5?apid=$mm_placementid&auid="
          . urlencode($mm_id) . "&ua=" . urlencode($mm_ua) . "&uip=" . urlencode($mm_id) . "&age=" . urlencode($age) . "&gender=" . urlencode($gender) . "&zip=" . urlencode($postalCode) . "&lat=" . urlencode($userLat) . "&long=" . urlencode($userLon);

/*------------ END AD INITIALIZATION -----------*/

// Use cURL request
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mm_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$adResult = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// display file
echo $adResult;
?>
```

Comment: By the way, I was able to get the MMedia ads to "flow" by using my PHP server to make the call (via their PHP sample) and have it return the information to the client via SSL.  I've updated my original comment with the sample code...captures some zipcode stuff from geonames as well (better ad targeting).